# Is there some kind of $0$-countable space?

Tags: general-topology

Is there some kind of $0$-countable space?

That for every $x\in X$ there exists at least continuum many neighborhood. Is anyone interested in such kind of non-first countable spaces? If so are these spaces interesting?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ has this property

Comment: Well... In $\Bbb Q$ every point has uncountably many neighbourhoods, but I presume you mean to say that, for all points, their neighbourhood basis have cardinality at least $\beth_1$.

Comment: If so, the notion you are looking for is the [character](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Character_(of_a_topological_space)) of the topological space. See also [cardinal invariants](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic).

Comment: But if I am not wrong $R$ is second countable?

Comment: @Jale'dejaled Yes it is, but the Euclidean topology $\tau$, as a set, has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ (id est, $\beth_1$), despite the existence of a countable subset $F\subseteq \tau$ such that every element of $\tau$ is union of a subfamily of $F$.

Comment: I see then my question is so trivial, thank you for your comments, no interesting idea here :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole theory of cardinal invariants in topology, with a large literature, that studies such questions. If you’re interested in local bases, you can define for a space $X$ and a point $p \in X$, the cardinal number $\chi(p,X)$ which is the minimal cardinal number of a local base at $p$. The character $\chi(X)$ is then defined as the supremum of all $\chi(p,X)$ over all $p \in X$. Elementary facts in set theory imply that these cardinals are always well-defined.

A first countable space is exactly one where we have $\chi(X) \le \aleph_0$.

It seems that what you want to call 0-countable is a space where $\min\{\chi(x,X)\mid x \in X\} \ge \mathfrak{c}$?